# Using Java profiler in Junit

Tags: java, junit, profiling, profiler

Is there a Java profiler that can be integrated as part of JUnit testing.

For example, I would like to have a condition that if a certain method in a test is using over X% of the CPU the test should fail/pass.

Or if a certain method is running for more than X amount of minutes it should fail.

I looked at YourKit, JVM monitor, and other suggested tools in here, as well as
running `java -Xrunhprof:cpu=samples,file=myprogram.hprof`

but all of these do not offer to be used as part of the test.

I would also be ok with invoking the profiler from the test, saving the results (automatically) to a csv/txt/any other file, and writing some code to extract the information.

An open source/free tool would be better, if such exists

Comment: I think you are way over shooting the scope of a unit test to be honest. Also its too easily influenced by different hardware/architecture and/or environment conditions. If you must, you can stick timeout on the tests: http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/rules/Timeout.html

Comment: I agree with @Damien's answer. JUnit is for functional testing, not performance testing. Anyway, you maybe could consider running JMeter tests.

Comment: I am mostly interested in seeing if a change to my program at any given time would make my code better/worst. 

My testing is running nightly based on JUnits (maybe I am over shooting here as well), and I just want to invoke some profiler with each run to see if something changed.

Comment: Running tests nightly is good, and recommended! To be honest, I think it would be easier for you to profile the app when you think any of your changes made an impact. If you are not comformable with hprof, you can use some vistual tool that comes with the JDK called JVisualVM. Also don't fall victim to premature optimization. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil

Answer (score 0):

JProfiler has an API that can be used for that purpose. In the JProfiler installation, look at the `api/samples/platform directory` and check out `src-profiler/TestProfiler.java`

As a rough outline, the code could look like this:

```
Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.getLocalConnection();

connection.recordCpuData(true);
// TODO execute unit test
connection.recordCpuData(false);

CpuHotspots cpuHotspots = connection.getCpuHotspots(null, Aggregation.METHOD,
        ThreadStatus.RUNNING, true);

List<ProfilingValue> hotspots = cpuHotspots.getHotspots();
Collections.sort(hotspots);
// TODO analyze hot spots

connection.close();
```

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler.

Comment: I am assuming JProfiler requires a license, or is this capability comes in a free version ?

Comment: JProfiler is a commercial product. It has a time-limited evaluation version, but no free version.